# ¿Cómo crear un loading personalizado con vuejs y elementui?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Muy buenas gente.

Estoy con la creación de un loading usando vuejs y elementui y me gustaría saber cómo personalizarlo.

En la documentación de elementui aparecen dos tipos diferentes pero lo que intento hacer es que en vez de mostrar el típico circulo que gira, mostrara un gif, llamase a algún otro componente o mostrara cualquier cosa editada por mi.
El ejemplo seria parecido a este.

```
<template>
  <el-button
    type="primary"
    @click="openFullScreen1"
    v-loading.fullscreen.lock="fullscreenLoading">
    As a directive
  </el-button>
  <el-button
    type="primary"
    @click="openFullScreen2">
    As a service
  </el-button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fullscreenLoading: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      openFullScreen1() {
        this.fullscreenLoading = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.fullscreenLoading = false;
        }, 2000);
      },
      openFullScreen2() {
        const loading = this.$loading({
          lock: true,
          text: 'Loading',
          spinner: 'el-icon-loading',
          background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          loading.close();
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Gracias

Comment: Podrías compartir el código de lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El componente no admite un fondo personalizado. La propiedad `background` se interpreta como un color.

Sin embargo... siempre puedes customizar el contenedor `.el-loading-mask` para mostrar el background que quieras. Eso puedes configurarlo individualmente por ejemplo dándole una clase custom

```
 this.$loading({
    customClass: 'mi_loader', // <- para distinguirlo de otros
    lock: true,
    text: 'Loading',
    spinner: 'el-icon-loading',
    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
 });
```

Y dándole un estilo como:

```
.el-loading-mask.mi_loader {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx8MT.gif);
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        tableData: [{
          date: '2016-05-02',
          name: 'John Smith',
          address: 'No.1518,  Jinshajiang Road, Putuo District'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'John Smith',
          address: 'No.1518,  Jinshajiang Road, Putuo District'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-01',
          name: 'John Smith',
          address: 'No.1518,  Jinshajiang Road, Putuo District'
        }],
        loading: true
      };
    },
    created() {
      this.$loading({
        customClass: 'mi_loader',
        lock: true,
        text: 'Loading',
        spinner: 'el-icon-loading',
        background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
      });
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.el-loading-mask.mi_loader {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx8MT.gif);
  color: black;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- import CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<!-- import JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" width="180">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="180">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="address" label="Address">
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </div>
</div>
```